# All infinite volume matrix product states are in different super-selection sectors?

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry-breaking, tensor-network

Consider two matrix product states $\Psi_1,\Psi_2$, i.e. let them be described (schematically) by

$$ \Psi_\alpha = \sum_{...i_n ...  } \left(\ell_{\alpha}, \left[\prod_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} E_\alpha(i) \right] r_\alpha\right) |\cdots i_n  \cdots \rangle \ . $$

Assume that the algebras generated by the $\{E_\alpha(i)\}_{i=1,..,d}$ are irreducible. Then the thermodynamic limit state does not depend on $\ell_\alpha, r_\alpha$. If $O$ is any local observable, then

$$ |\langle \Psi_1, O \Psi_2 \rangle| = |\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \text{tr}( \mathbb{E}_{12}^N  \mathbb{E}_O ) | \lesssim \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \| \mathbb{E}_{12}\|^N  \ , \ \ \mathbb{E}_{12}(X) = \sum_{i=1}^d E_1(i) X E_2(i)^* \ ; $$

here $\mathbb{E}_O$ is some linear operator given in terms of the $E_\alpha(i)$ and matrix elements of $O$. Then according to [these lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.07006) either

(i) there is an invertible $g$ s.t. $g E_1(i) g^{-1} = E_2(i)$ or

(ii) $\| \mathbb{E}_{12}\| < 1$.

In the case (i), $\Psi_1 = \Psi_2$ while in the latter case $\langle \Psi_1, O \Psi_2\rangle = 0$ for all local observables! The authors of the above paper call this 'orthogonality catastrophe' in reminiscence of the [classical result by Anderson](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.18.1049). However, it is even more drastic, since not only are these states orthogonal, but they lie in completely different super-selection sectors!

This can be understood by considering the set of mean-field states only. Within the matrix-product world, these are the states with bond dimensions $1$, and may be thus written as

$$ \widehat{\psi} := \cdots \otimes \psi \otimes \cdots \otimes \psi \otimes \cdots \ , $$

where $\psi$ is some vector of the on-site Hilbert space. Again, two different mean-field states will have

$$ \langle \widehat{\psi}, O \widehat{\phi} \rangle = 0 \ \text{unless} \ \psi = \phi $$

for all local observables $O$.

Usually, if there is for example an on-site symmetry group $G$, one would say that this symmetry is thus broken.

My questions:

(1) Where could i find some literature about super-selection sectors in one-dimensional quantum spin systems?

(2) It seems really counterintuitive to have this huge manifold of symmetry-breaking states if related to the fact that in one space dimension, continuous symmetries should not be broken.

Comment: In which sense do these lie in different superselection sectors? You would have to define a symmetry first (and it probably would have to be a continuous one, even if you only have two states).

Comment: I am refering to the definition of super-selection sectors as subspaces $H_1,H_2$ of a total Hilbert space $H$ such that superpositions between vectors of $H_1$ with vectors from $H_2$ are meaningless since there are no operators connecting the two spaces; this is the property "$\langle \Psi_1, O \Psi_2\rangle = 0$ for all local observables".

Comment: I thought superselection sectors are defined by different quantum numbers?  (Which means that local observables can, in principle, produce some overlap, like creation operators between different particle number sectors!  This is only impossible for *symmetry-preserving* operators - however, there is no notion of locality there, *no* symmetry-preserving operator can couple different superselection sectors.)

Comment: So i am using the definition given for example in Wightman and Streaters book, "PCT, Spin-Statistics and all that". There is not much of a difference though since a super-selection sector implies a conserved charge. (not the other way around though). To your example, of sectors of different particle numbers: of course one first has to define what the set of allowed operators is. In the case here the important restriction is the one to local operators. Indeed, the statement does not hold for operators of infinite support (although i am not sure whether these would be well-defined).

Comment: What is the conserved charge if the superselection rule is "local operators only"?

Comment: So are you questioning whether the claimed property actually holds, i mean that for all local operators $O$, the matrix elements of $O$ between two $D<\infty$ mps states are only non-zero if they are identical? Because if you agree with that, then just take a decomposition of Hilbert space into all super-selection sectors. Then any operator which is proportional to the identity on any individual sector is a conserved charge. If you are asking for an interpretation of any of these charges: i have no idea! This is somehow my question (2), i'd say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96346/discussion-between-lorenz-mayer-and-norbert-schuch).